# With serverless-bundle, how can I run tests over code that uses the sharp package?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, jestjs, serverless-framework, sharp

I am using the sharp package and serverless-bundle together in a serverless-framework project. I am able to run and deploy my code just fine with this `custom.bundle.packagerOptions.scripts` script: `rm -rf node_modules/sharp && npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=10.15.0 sharp`.

When I try to run a test over code that touches the sharp package, I get the following error: `'linux-x64' binaries cannot be used on the 'darwin-x64' platform. Please remove the 'node_modules/sharp/vendor' directory and run 'npm install'.`

I don't plan on testing the implementation of sharp, rather, I am mocking the JavaScript file that is importing it. Here is the test file where I am running into this issue: https://github.com/groffcole/art-center-service/blob/master/ports/GalleriesHttpPort.test.js

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue just by chance. I deleted my entire `node_modules` directory and ran `npm install`. I believe because I'm using the `serverless-bundle` package, wires were getting crossed. I can now run tests successfully using the `serverless-bundle test` command.

For reference, here are my custom `serverless-bundle` settings in my `serverless.yml` file:

```
custom:
  bundle:
    caching: false
    packagerOptions:
      scripts:
        - rm -rf node_modules/sharp && npm install --arch=x64 --platform=linux --target=10.15.0 sharp
```